# A Newtonian problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I tried to imagine what would happen to a theoretical astronaut in the following thought experiment. The astronaut floats in space with the velocity of zero. He/she has a 10kg object and a wall 2 meters away (it floats in one place too). The wall and the object both have a(n) elasticity (coefficient of restitution) of 0.99. What exactly happens when the astronaut throws the object towards the wall? Because in my interpretation, when the object is tossed away with the force of x, the astronaut accelerates in the opposite direction with the same amount of impulse. And when it collides with the wall it bounces back, the wall pushes a bit and the object bounces back towards the astronaut. When he/she catches it again, the momentum of it accelerates a bit again on the person. And the object gains upon because its mass is like 10% the astronaut and it has more speed. Please help me solve this problem because I cannot get a good night's sleep until I figure this one out. Thanks in advance for pointing out any errors in my model.

Comment: Re, "when the object is tossed away with the force of x, the astronaut accelerates in the opposite direction with the same amount." Same amount of _what?_ I think that, in order to adequately describe this problem, you need to use the word, "impulse." In physics, an [_impulse_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) is a change in momentum. Since momentum is a conserved quantity, when a "floating" astronaut throws a ball, the impulse that the astronaut delivers to the ball must be equal and opposite the impulse that the ball delivers to the astronaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no external forces acting on the total system of astronaut, ball and wall. So if the centre of mass of the system is initially at rest (e.g in a reference frame in which the astronaut and the wall are both initially at rest) then it will remain at rest.

So after the astronaut has thrown the ball, it has bounced off the wall, and the astronaut has caught the ball again then the momentum of the wall will be equal and opposite to the momentum of the astronaut and ball. In other words the wall and the astronaut/ball will be moving in opposite directions with speeds that are inversely proportional to their masses.

Comment: I must be imagining this wrong, because I don't see how the astronaut could catch the ball. The astronaut throws the ball at the wall with speed +V, and (s)he drifts away with speed -V, the ball hits the wall and bounces off, let's say elastically with speed -V, and now the ball and the astronaut are travelling in the same direction, with the same speed, but the astronaut had a head start. How could the ball ever catch up? And in the inelastic case, the ball would bounce off slower, which is no better. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @electronpusher After the throw the astronaut and the ball will have equal and opposite momentum, which does not imply equal and opposite speeds. The astronaut has a higher mass than the ball (the ball’s mass is only $10$ kg) and so will have a lower speed.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you. I'm rustier on my mechanics than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

As @gandalf61 noted that there is no external force the center of the mass stays still till the object and the astronaut hits to the wall. Then because the collisions are not fully elastic there will be some loss in energy and also momentum (between astronout and the object). Considering the amount of defect center of the mass can change but for the given elasticity coefficient collision will not alter the result as you interpreted in the answer.

Comment: Loss of kinetic energy, yes, but loss of system momentum? By what mechanism if there are no external forces. There's no transfer of momentum outside the system. Non-elasticity does not change momentum.

Comment: @BillN you are right I meant the total momentum for object and the astronout changes.

Comment: @BillN thanks for showing the error.